# How to delete database table when session gets destroyed?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making chat app using  html, css , js ,php , mysql. Whenever users gets logged in , i have run sql query that will add that user as activeuserlist table but how to delete that activeuserlist table whenever his session gets destroyed?

Comment: **his session gets destroyed** - do  you mean when the user has "logged out"？

Comment: You get **not** feedback if the user gets logged out by time (user did not come back, session expired). _The only time you would get this is if the user clicks on "logout", but who does that, right?_ So you can just add a datetime or timestamp in your db to log when the user was `last_seen`. You then can calculate few min back to decide if the user (still) counts as "online", or if he is "too long" inactive and counts as "offline".

Answer (score 0):

How can you know if a user closes the browser?

It needs web-socket like [Ratchet](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet)

Or can be with ajax ( less productive - it has to hit the url periodically to keep the status of the user online )